# Multiple query orderBy clauses Firebase - Java

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to query my `Messages` table for three things. The first is any messages with that involve the current user logged in. Then, I want to get the user id of the person the current user has a coversation with. And finally, I want to check if any of the messages were seen. But right now my query only runs the first and last queries and not the second one. But I don't know why.

[image: Messages table]

```
FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

DatabaseReference userMessageKeyRef = dbRef.child("Messages").child(firebaseUser.getUid());
userMessageKeyRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()) {

            String messageToID = snapshot1.getKey();

            DatabaseReference messageRef = dbRef.child("Messages").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child(messageToID);
            Query query = messageRef.orderByChild("to").equalTo(firebaseUser.getUid());
            query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    long count = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();

                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                        DatabaseReference messageKeyRef = dbRef.child("Messages").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child(messageToID);
                        Query query2 =  messageKeyRef.orderByChild("isSeen").equalTo(false);

                        query2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataShot) {

                                if (dataShot.exists() && count > 0) {

                                    //Log.d("TAG2", "count if: " + count2);
                                    messages_text.setText("" + Math.toIntExact(count));
                                    messages_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                } else {

                                    messages_text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                            }
                        });

                    } else {

                        messages_text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });

            //Log.d("TAG1", "User to: " + messageToID);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    }
});
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AlexMamo wow can't believe I missed this. No, no errors. Frank's answer works somewhat with a bug in it. I explained in the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first `addValueEventListener` already loads all data for the current user, so there is no need to go back to the database to load that data again. Instead you should check the properties of each message in your application code with something like:

```
DatabaseReference userMessageKeyRef = dbRef.child("Messages").child(firebaseUser.getUid());
userMessageKeyRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    for (DataSnapshot parentSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
        for (DataSnapshot messageSnapshot : addValueEventListener.getChildren()) {
            String messageToID = messageSnapshot.getKey();
            String toValue = messageSnapshot.child("to").getValue(String.class);
            Boolean isSeenValue = messageSnapshot.child("isSeen").getValue(Boolean.class);

            if (toValue.equals(firebaseUser.getUid()) && isSeenValue == true) {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: When I do that, `toValue` and `isSeenValue` both come back null. But `messageToID` comes back correct.

Comment: Ah yeah, I now see I was missing a loop. I added that to the code in my answer. If that still doesn't work, I recommend setting some breakpoints and running in a debugger to see what the values and snapshots look like.

Comment: I have this condition `if (currentUserID == toValue && !isSeenValue)`  there are three values and one of them has the current user logged in. But the condition doesn't return any records

Comment: That's not how you compare strings in Java. They require `equals` as I showed in my answer.

Comment: Yeah I tried that along with a million different things and nothing happened. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73616167/if-statement-should-return-results-but-doesnt